# Encountered error while trying to install package Pandas

Tags: python, pandas, api

Has anyone here ever messed with google colab?
Do not try to install the library but always "pip install google-colab" it returns this Pandas error. I've tried uninstalling and reinstalling Pandas but it still didn't work either.

I need to do some data extraction within the DV360 platform via API.

[This is the error image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/osJgo.jpg)

Comment: `python -m pip install --force-reinstall pandas` didn't help?

Comment: yes I tried this command but it didn't work either

Comment: whenever i try to import google-colab library through pip it returns me this error in pandas.

Comment: Something has mangled your environment. It's probably easiest to start over with a new environment. Consider working with [conda](https://docs.conda.io/projects/conda/en/latest/user-guide/install/windows.html) in the future.

Comment: When you say "start with a new environment" what exactly do you mean?